# Member registration form error

Tags: error, registration, member-management

We recently upgraded EE (2.7.2) and run Solspace User (3.4.4) plugin.

Our client side registration form no longer works. Upon submission we get 
“You are not authorized to perform this action”

Any clue?

Thanks,
L.

Answer (score 2):

In the Solspace changelog for Solspace User in 3.4.5 it states: "Updated User submission forms to be compatible with EE 2.7+."

I suggest updating Solspace User to the latest version so it is compatible with 2.7+. And a little Developer advice. Don't update everything when a new version comes out, unless it fixes a bug you are having, security, or add's a new feature you need. I have sites that are still on 2.4 because I have third party plug-ins, modules, fieldtypes, and accessories that haven't been updated or would change things I don't want. This is my opinion, if something works and nothing is wrong don't worry about updating.